# search in SQLite android java not work

Tags: java, android, sqlite, search, cursor

I am trying to fetch data from sqlite data base .I already have a table for employees and I want to fetch employee info by employee name.I already created a function in the database helper like this:

```html
public  List getEmpdat(String empname) {

        final String TABLE_NAME = "Employee";

        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM Employee where EmployeeName="+empname;
        SQLiteDatabase db  = this.getReadableDatabase();
        List<String> li = new ArrayList<String>();
        Cursor cursor      = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        String[] data      = null;
       // String name =null;

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                String  name=cursor.getString(2);
                String notes=cursor.getString(3);
                String strdate=cursor.getString(4);
                if(strdate==null)
                    strdate = "0";
                String gate=cursor.getString(6);
                if(gate==null)
                    gate = "0";
                String enddate=cursor.getString(5);
                if(enddate==null)
                    enddate = "0";
                li.add(name);
                li.add(notes);
                li.add(strdate);
                li.add(enddate);
                li.add(gate);


                // get the data into array, or class variable
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        cursor.close();
        return li;
    }
```

and then call it in the search activity like this :

```html
  db=new DataBaseHelper(this);
        data = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView);
        List<String> li = new ArrayList<String>();
        li = db.getEmpdat(editName.getText().toString());
        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, li);
        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.activity_search);

        dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, li);
        data.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
```

but there is a problem taking place from the logcat the problem is 
"                                                                               java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.university.newapp/com.example.university.newapp.SearchActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "=": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT  * FROM Employee where EmployeeName=
"
can any one provide help with this issue please

Comment: string value is always need '' in rawquery so use    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM Employee where EmployeeName='"+empname+"'";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change the line where exception occurred and check if it works.

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM Employee where EmployeeName='"+empname+"'";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use placeholder in querying, like that,

```
String query = String.format("SELECT  * FROM Employee WHERE EmployeeName='%s'",empname);
```

You will see `'%s'`,it serve as placeholder and your variable value will be insert to placeholder when querying.
So, `'%s'` can be use for `String` placeholder and if you want for `Digit` , you can use `'%d'`.I hope this will help for you.